# nutch not indexing specifig teg in solr

Tags: solr, nutch

i am using extractor plug-in. 
    https://github.com/BayanGroup/nutch-custom-search
    I follow mentioned step on github.
    here is my configuration:
    1)  extractors.xml
    
            
    
        
            
                
                    
                         title" />

```
2) nutch-site.xml
<property>
  <name>plugin.includes</name>
  <value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(text|html|metatags|msexcel|msword|mspowerpoint|pdf)|extractor|scoring-opic|index-(basic|anchor|more|metadata)|query-(basic|site|url|lang)|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
</property>
3)  added field in schema.xml of solr and nutch   <field name="aakashtitle" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
4)I added plugin in parse-plugins.xml
I am not getting any error but my data is not indexing in solr??
please help . and thanks!
```

Comment: 1)  extractors.xml
<fields>
        <field name="aakashtitle" multi="true" />
</fields>
    <documents>
        <document url=".+" engine="css">
            <extract-to field="aakashtitle">
                <text>
                    <expr value="head > title" />
                </text>
          </extract-to>
        </document>
    </documents>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick look to the GH repository, since the code actually works like a normal `ParseFilter` you should be able to check if the data is correctly being pulled by using the `parsechecker` command:

```
$ bin/nutch parsechecker <URL>
```

This should output the usual data extracted by Nutch (contentType, signature, url) and the `ParseData` (status, title, outlinks, etc.) and also any additional info extracted from the plugin.

You could also use the `indexchecker` command:

```
$ bin/nutch indexchecker <URL>
```

This will output the actual fields that are going to be indexed by the active indexing plugin (Solr/ES).

Comment: Thanks! it is working now. but i want to build our own plug-in for nucth for extract specific tags. any idea?

Comment: You can implement your own plugin as an `HTMLParseFilter` if you do, take a look at https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/plugin/headings/src/java/org/apache/nutch/parse/headings/HeadingsParseFilter.java which is a basic extraction plugin, easy to understand. Also you can use https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1870 it's a WIP and perhaps you need to tweak the patch to work on trunk/1.11 but it's a good starting point and will let you use XPath to specify what data to extract.

Comment: Thank you soo much! i will try now to write my own plug-in for extract specif tags